# Django: Loaddata command after syncdb fails

Tags: django

I'm trying to use fixtures as a DB-agnostic way to get the data into my database, but this is much harder than it should be. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong...

Specifically, **when I do a syncdb followed by a migrate followed by a loaddata** I run into trouble, since **syncdb already creates data that loaddata tries to read from the dump**. This leads to double entries and hence a crashing script.

This seems to be the same problem as described here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15926

But it's weird to me that this seems to be an ignored issue. Are fixtures not meant to actually put real (live) data in?

If so: is there any Django-format that is meant for this? Or is everyone just dumping data as SQL? And, if so, how would one migrate development data in SQLite to a production database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here; this is what I came up with so far:

```
# some_app/management/commands/delete_all_objects.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.db.models import get_models

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Deletes all objects'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for model in get_models():
            model.objects.all().delete()
```

And then just run delete_all_objects between after `syncdb` & `migrate` and before `loaddata`. I'm not sure I like it, I'm very surprised it's necessary, but it works.

Comment: Can you rename the fixture files? If so, why not rename them to something that syncdb won't pick up, and then when you call loaddata the data won't be in the database already.

Comment: I technically could rename them; but since everything is running in scripts (and a mistake will erase all data) this is a bit fragile for my taste

Answer (score 1):

syncdb will also load data from fixtures if you have the fixtures named correctly and in the correct location. See this link for more info.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

If you do not want the data to load on every syncdb then you will need to change the name of the fixture.

fixtures are an OK way to load your data, I have used it on a number of projects. On some projects when I have a ton of data I sometimes write a special load script that will take the data from my data source and load up my new django models, the custom script is a little more work, but gives you more flexibility.

I tend to stay away from using sql to load if I can, since SQL is usually DB specific, if you have to worry about loading on different database versions, stay away if you can.

"In general, using a fixture is a cleaner method since it’s database-agnostic, but initial SQL is also quite a bit more flexible."

Comment: In the link you provided: "remember that the data will be refreshed every time you run syncdb. So don't use initial_data for data you'll want to edit." - not quite what I'm looking for I guess... I'll try something else